# How to animate text cycle with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have a text cycling feature I want to use on a website.

The way it works is listed below:

HTML & Javascript

```
<h1 class="intro-title">This is some text 
    <span id="changer">This text changes</span>
</h1>

<script>
var words = ["changes to this", "changes to that", "changes to there"];
var i = 0;
var text = "This text changes";

function _getChangedText() {
    i = (i + 1) % words.length;
    return text.replace(/This text changes/, words[i]);
}

function _changeText() {
    var txt = _getChangedText();
    document.getElementById("changer").innerHTML = txt;
}
setInterval("_changeText()", 1800);
</script>
```

This works fine and cycles through the options fine. I am wanting to animate this script, so the text rotates upwards and fades into the next text option. Is there something I can add to this script, or will it need to be written again?

Any assistance is appreciated.

There's a JSfiddle attached: https://jsfiddle.net/g59phn0b/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a CSS `fadeOut` class for the animation and add it during `_changeText()`. Then remove this class after animation. Add a `fadeIn` class for the next element if needed. Use `setTimeout();` to time rotation with your css.

**CSS**

```
.fadeOut{
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0; 
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
       -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;
        -ms-transition: all 1s ease-out;
         -o-transition: all 1s ease-out;
            transition: all 1s ease-out;
  transform: translate(0,-50px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0,-50px);
  -o-transform: translate(0,-50px); 
  -moz-transform: translate(0,-50px);
}
```

**JS**

```
function _changeText() {
    var txt = _getChangedText();
    var d = document.getElementById("changer")
    d.className = "fadeOut";
    setTimeout(function(){
        d.className = "";
        d.innerHTML = txt;
    }, 1000);
}
```

Here an edited **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g59phn0b/2/)** with `fadeOut`. Just do the same with a `fadeIn` and you have your desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

How is it working? I get an error, and I needed to change

```
setInterval("_changeText()", 1800);
```

to

```
setInterval(_changeText, 1800);
```

to get it working

No Need for pattern matching, or your text variable, you can just simply return words[i]

```
function _getChangedText() {
    i = (i + 1) % words.length;
    return words[i];
}
```

You can add the rotations with CSS to Hosch Nok's solution, or pursue a canvas option.

```
.fadeOut{
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: visibility 0s 1s, opacity 1s linear;
    -webkit-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(-360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg); transform:rotate(-360deg); } }
```